attempting to use HID controller as Input using python
Im using the following code to read(and name) the inputs of an HID device. is anyone aware of a program that I can use to translate the HID inputs to maybe something like a virtual controller? thanks in advance!
import hid

# Define vendor and product IDs of your HID device
vendor_id = 0x04DE
product_id = 0xEAB8

# Open a connection to the HID device
device = hid.device()
device.open(vendor_id, product_id)

# Define constants for parsing input reports
POTENTIOMETER_OFFSET = 0
ROTARY_ENCODER_OFFSET = 11
PUSH_BUTTON_OFFSET = 12
ROTARY_SWITCH_OFFSET = 16
SWITCH_OFFSET = 17

try:
    # Main loop to continuously read input reports
    while True:
        # Read an input report from the HID device
        input_report = device.read(64)  # Adjust buffer size according to your HID device
        
        # Process the input report
        if input_report:
            # Parse potentiometer values
            potentiometer_values = input_report[POTENTIOMETER_OFFSET:POTENTIOMETER_OFFSET + 11]
            # Process potentiometer values as needed
            
            # Parse rotary encoder value
            rotary_encoder_value = input_report[ROTARY_ENCODER_OFFSET]
            # Process rotary encoder value as needed
            
            # Parse push button states
            push_button_states = input_report[PUSH_BUTTON_OFFSET:PUSH_BUTTON_OFFSET + 4]
            # Process push button states as needed
            
            # Parse rotary switch value
            rotary_switch_value = input_report[ROTARY_SWITCH_OFFSET]
            # Process rotary switch value as needed
            
            # Parse switch states
            switch_states = input_report[SWITCH_OFFSET:SWITCH_OFFSET + 11]
            # Process switch states as needed

            # Example: Print parsed values
            print("Potentiometer values:", potentiometer_values)
            print("Rotary encoder value:", rotary_encoder_value)
            print("Push button states:", push_button_states)
            print("Rotary switch value:", rotary_switch_value)
            print("Switch states:", switch_states)
            
            # Perform actions based on parsed input data
            
        else:
            print("No input report received")

except KeyboardInterrupt:
    # Close the HID device when the program is interrupted
    device.close()


Readout of button/switch states
attempted to use pyvjoy and vgamepad but there are not enough buttons(let alone the fact I couldnt get the code to work lol)
